# can not get the scope of 2nd controller withing same angular file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using two controllers for my home page.
1. A controller to handle search autocomplete (google maps api to suggest locations).
2. Another controller to handle remaining parts of the page

But the scope of the second controller just does not show up.

**EJS:**

```
<head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/locationController.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/mainController.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />

    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA67uROXPqm2Nnfg5HOTHttn2C7QRn1zIo&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>

    <script src="ngAutocomplete/script.js"></script>
    <script src="ngAutocomplete/ngAutoComplete.js"></script>
  </head>



            <li class="ul_One"  ng-controller="searchBarController">

                    <div id="inLine" class="col-lg-12 ul_Two" style="">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control ul_Three" id="Autocomplete" placeholder="Where to?" ng-autocomplete="result1" details="details1" options="options1" ng-model="destination">
                    </div>

            </li>

            <li class="ul_One"  ng-controller="testController">

                    <div id="inLine" class="col-lg-12 ul_Two" style="">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control ul_Three" id="Autocomplete" placeholder="Where to?" ng-autocomplete="result1" details="details1" options="options1" ng-model="destination">
                    </div>

            </li>
```

**locationController.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//home page main controller  //home page main controller  
//home page main controller  //home page main controller  
app.controller('searchBarController', function($scope, $http) {


    $scope.test = "Hello";
    console.log("$scope.test ", $scope.test);

});
//home page main controller  //home page main controller  
//home page main controller  //home page main controller
```

**mainController.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//home page main controller  //home page main controller  
//home page main controller  //home page main controller  
app.controller('testController', function($scope, $http) {


    $scope.test = "Hello";
    console.log("$scope.test ", $scope.test);

});
//home page main controller  //home page main controller  
//home page main controller  //home page main controller
```

Comment: you dont need app module defined twice. every time you pass in an empty array to the module it would try to create a new one. you should have only one app module with [] as a second argument. Angular is most of the times, developer friendly. You console speaks for you about the errors.

Comment: Check the console for any error as you are creating the module two times. Create a module and assign it to 'window.app=app' then use the same in the second controller as 'var app = window.app'

Comment: @Sreekanth Even if I write both the controllers in the same file with just one module definition, the same problem persists.

Comment: what exactly you meant by scope doesnt show up on second controller?

Comment: @jack did u call the myApp in the template?

Comment: @jack please look at my code below which is a working copy of your code.

Comment: @jack have a look at my answer which might help you.!! any other queries?

Comment: @jack!! is your problem fixed

Answer (score 1):

You have created the `angular module` two times in each controller file. I have changed this by creating a module in one file and assign it to `window.app` then use the same in the second file.

Instead, you can call `angular.module('myApp')` in the second file without the second argument which will return the module created in the first file.

```js
// File 1: locationController.js

(function(){
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
window.app = app;

//home page main controller  //home page main controller  
//home page main controller  //home page main controller  
app.controller('searchBarController', function($scope, $http) {


    $scope.destination = "Hello";
    //console.log("$scope.test ", $scope.test);

});
//home page main controller  //home page main controller  
//home page main controller  //home page main controller
})();

// File 2: mainController.js:

(function(){
var app = window.app;
// It can be also as below,
//var app = angular.module('myApp');
  
//home page main controller  //home page main controller  
//home page main controller  //home page main controller  
app.controller('testController', function($scope, $http) {


    $scope.destination = "Hello";
    //console.log("$scope.test ", $scope.test);

});
//home page main controller  //home page main controller  
//home page main controller  //home page main controller
})();

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<li class="ul_One"  ng-controller="searchBarController">

                    <div id="inLine" class="col-lg-12 ul_Two" style="">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control ul_Three" id="Autocomplete" placeholder="Where to?" ng-autocomplete="result1" details="details1" options="options1" ng-model="destination">
                    </div>

            </li>

            <li class="ul_One"  ng-controller="testController">

                    <div id="inLine" class="col-lg-12 ul_Two" style="">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control ul_Three" id="Autocomplete" placeholder="Where to?" ng-autocomplete="result1" details="details1" options="options1" ng-model="destination">
                    </div>

            </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made your code to reach both the controllers.

Have a look at that is

**[Plukr](https://plnkr.co/edit/A2Rcs9?p=preview)**

Also in your code and the javascript reference was throwing an exception **SensorNotRequired** which can be further explored in this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required).
I fixed it by removing the sensor querystring in the url.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA67uROXPqm2Nnfg5HOTHttn2C7QRn1zIo&libraries=places">

</script>
```

To show case it is working I might have added a lable in the HTML.. 
Have a glance at it.

Comment: which one of the two?

Comment: I meant not your's